# How to fix CORB(Cross-Origin Read Blocking) error of google chrome in node.js?

Tags: node.js, google-chrome, npm, paypal-rest-sdk, cross-origin-read-blocking

I am trying to make a checkout using paypal-rest-sdk and when after successful response it is redirecting to the approval_url then it is giving error as given below.

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9TM98470K35457508 with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

```
paypal.payment.create(create_payment_json, function (error, payment) {
    if (error) {
        res.status(500).json({success: false,msg:'error -'+ error});
    }
    else {
        for(var i = 0; i < payment.links.length; i++){
            if(payment.links[i].rel === 'approval_url' && 
                payment.links[i].method === 'REDIRECT'){
                 //  this is coming in console
                console.log('payment is processing');
                 // error is coming here when redirecting to payment gate
                res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

It should successfully redirect to the payment gateway.

Answer (score 1):

The error is coming from your **browser**, not from Node.js.

You need to consider your browser-side code.

It sounds like you are making an HTTP request using Ajax and expecting to get JSON back. You are responding with either a 500 error and some JSON or a redirect to some HTML.

Since the client is expecting JSON, it complains.

It sounds like you shouldn't be using Ajax in the first place.

Comment: @Rupesh — The browser is making an HTTP request to an end point supplied by your Node application. Your node application is runing `res.redirect(payment.links[i].href);` which causes it to respond to the browser with a redirect to `https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout&token=EC-9TM98470K35457508`. That URL is an HTML document. The browser complains because it is expecting something other than an HTML document. I refer you to the first 2 paragraphs of my answer. The last 3 paragraphs are speculative because you haven't provided an [mcve] of the browser-side code.

Comment: I have already written that I am using npm package of paypal-rest-sdk so the code will be same as given in npm docs of paypal-rest-sdk. But sorry for that will keep in mind.

Comment: @Rupesh — The [documentation for `paypal-rest-sdk`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/paypal-rest-sdk) suggests it is responsible for the function `paypal.payment.create` which appears in your Node.js code but includes no code designed to run in the browser … so you must have written that code yourself … which I've repeatedly said is relevant.

Comment: @Rupesh — That appears to be entirely JS you run in Node and not the JS you run in the browser.

Comment: Here is the code that I have used in my angular service https://pastebin.com/tMLNmRN1  and in the above link I have posted the route to integrate with paypal .

Comment: @Rupesh — And what do you expect `this.http.post<responseFromApi>('/paypal/pay', bookName, httpOptions);` to do with the HTML document it gets after following the redirect you give it?

Comment: It should only redirect to paypal approve_url if the post request is successful else it should give res.status(500).json({success: false, msg:'failed payment}); @Quentin

Comment: @Rupesh — It is successful. It does redirect. If it didn't, you wouldn't see the Paypay URL you were redirecting to in the error message!